# Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.contacts.filter') in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie in react native and I encountered the following problem while working on a sample chat app in android emulator.

Its showing the error

**`Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.contacts.filter')`**

in the line of code

```
let filteredContacts = this.state.contacts.filter(
       (contact) => {
          return contact.name.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
       }
);
```

Here is the code I'm working on.

```
    componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({contacts : this.props.navigation.state.params.contacts});   


    render() {
          let filteredContacts = this.state.contacts.filter(
            (contact) => {
              return contact.name.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
            }
          );
          return (
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                <TextInput style={styles.searchbar} placeholder="Search"
                  onChange={(search) => {this.setState({search: search, isContactSearch: true}); this.onSearchPress}} />
                {!this.state.isContactSearch && 
                  <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    renderItem={this.renderFlatListItem}
                    data={this.state.historyContactList}  
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}>
                  </FlatList>
                }
                {this.state.isContactSearch && 
                  <FlatList>
                    {filteredContacts.map((contact) => {
                      return <View key={contact.number}>{contact.name}</View>
                    })}
                  </FlatList>
                }
            </View>
          );
        }
```

Comment: make sure `this.state.contacts` will be an array, check the initial value as well as all the places where you are doing setState.

Comment: mention your initial contact state first

Answer (score 1):

The `componentDidMount` callback runs only after the first render, so the state you set there isn't available on the first render pass.

You can move the state initialization logic to `constructor` instead:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    contacts: props.navigation.state.params.contacts
  };
}
```

Note that here we set the state using regular javascript assignment instead of `setState`, because the latter is asynchronous and not safe to call in the constructor. If you want to later modify the state, you'll need to use `setState` as you have now.

Comment: This won't react to update props though right? Also is a sync setState recommended? AFAIK the above method if used outside of the constructor will not re-render the component, so maybe overall its not a good practise, just my 2 cents

Comment: Well, generally speaking replicating evolving props into state is somewhat of an antipattern, but you _can_ do that in `componentWillReceiveProps` with a `setState`. More here: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Answer (score 1):

Since componentDidMount is called after your render method your initial state value is not initialized! You can do 2 things here,

1) Set an initial value for your state params in the constructor if this is a one time setup you need!

2) If you want the state to update before every render you can copy the same code into componentWillMount/componentWillReceiveProps